# How to get all dependencies for Hibernate Search Lucene using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, lucene, hibernate-search

My build.gradle file:

```
//Hibernate
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.2.Final'

//Hibernate Search
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-search:5.11.1.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final'
implementation 'org.apache.solr:solr-common:1.3.0'
implementation 'org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.6.0'
implementation 'org.lucee:lucene-snowball:2.9.4'
```

When I ran ./gradlew clean jar in IntelliJ, I've got the error:

12:40:34: Executing task 'jar'...

> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:2.3.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.6.0
  >   Could not find org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.servlet:2.3.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.6.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Could not find org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:2.3.0.
Required by:
    project : > org.apache.solr:solr-core:7.6.0
Search in build.gradle files
12:40:38: Task execution finished 'jar'.

Comment: The build fails because some dependencies are not available using the configured repositories. Can you add `jcenter()` the the repositories? Restlet should be available there

Comment: I think these ones are in Maven repositories. I will try to use Hibernate Search without solr-core jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr is not necessary to use Hibernate Search. Try removing the Solr dependencies.

If you added these dependencies to use extra analyzers, you may want to know that in the past few years most analyzers were moved from Solr to Lucene, and thus you should be able to depend on Lucene jars instead: [see here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.lucene%20a:lucene-analyzers*)